# Xcode gives error when I add libraries: dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, glfw

First I wanted to learn SDL in xcode, but when I try to add SDL framework this error pops up and I can't understand why. I looked on the internet for 2 days but couldn't find any solution. After 1 month (now) I'm trying to add GLFW to xcode but this error got me again. Why is this error happening?

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/durdukolk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Graphic-dutmtfjytmmfetggltqeajfkggms/Build/Products/Debug/Graphic
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/opt/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/opt/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
    /usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.4/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.4/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
```

[image: Link Binary with libraries]

[image: Search Paths]

Answer (score 8):

I finally found the solution.First you need to open "Enable hardened runtime" in section Signing in the project file.
[image: Project Name -> Build Setting -> Signing -> Enable Hardened Runtime]

And need the check "Disable Library Validation" at product menu.
[image: Target Name -> Signing & Capabilities -> Hardened Runtime -> Disable Library Validation]

For more detail: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_cs_disable-library-validation

Comment: Does not work for iOS.